# WCF database wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, database, performance, wcf

I need to do a WCF service to wrap up the database access. I do not want the service to be bind to any specific database. In fact, it will only receives a query and returns a dataset. no treatement on the data will be done in the service so I want pure performance but it need to be secure too.

Actually, I think using perCall session, net.tcp binding and certificate autentification on both side. (it's a WAN app)

Still, can someone give some advices on the configuration that I should use?(Type of Session,Type of binding,Type of security,etc..)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with net.tcp, but I do know that it's a fast binding for doing stuff like this. So you're on the right track there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you could take advantage of [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).

> WCF Data Services  (formerly known as
>   "ADO.NET Data Services") is a
>   component of the .NET Framework that
>   enables you to create services that
>   use the Open Data Protocol (OData)  to
>   expose and consume data over the Web
>   or intranet by using the semantics of
>   representational state transfer
>   (REST). OData  exposes data as
>   resources that are addressable by
>   URIs. Data is accessed and changed by
>   using standard HTTP verbs of GET, PUT,
>   POST, and DELETE. OData uses the
>   entity-relationship conventions of the
>   Entity Data Model to expose resources
>   as sets of entities that are related
>   by associations.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a deeper look on this component. Is there a easy way to secure the transfer(I need secure the query and the result)?

Comment: This looks like a good resource: http://mtaulty.com/communityserver/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/05/27/10447.aspx